# Delete Command Bars > 1 occurence

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a third party add-in. My issue is, it counts the last command bar loaded and if not there, it re-loads it.

I do not want to edit their code as with updates etc., it would need changing every time.

Is there a way I can delete all command bars but one or change the load order to avoid this issue?

```
Public Sub ABCInitializeAddin()

Dim menuEntries As Integer
Dim lastIndex As Integer

' Get number of menu entries
menuEntries = Application.CommandBars(WorksheetMenuBar).Controls.Count

' Get index of last entry
lastIndex = Application.CommandBars(WorksheetMenuBar).Controls(menuEntries).Index

If Not Application.CommandBars(WorksheetMenuBar).Controls(lastIndex - 1).Caption = ABCMenuEntry Then

    ' Add main menu entry
    Dim ABCMainMenu As CommandBarControl
    Set ABCMainMenu = CommandBars(WorksheetMenuBar).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=lastIndex)
    ABCMainMenu.Caption = ABCMenuEntry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub STDeleteXavex()

    Dim menuEntries As Integer
    Dim lastIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim count As Long

    count = -1

    ' Get number of menu entries
    menuEntries = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.count

    For i = 1 To menuEntries:
        If Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls(i).Caption = "&ABC Online" Then count = count + 1
    Next i

    For p = 1 To count:
        Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("ABC Online").Delete
    Next p

End Sub
```